# Autocomplete in Mathematica 13

Tags: bugs, front-end, autocomplete, version-13

**Bug introduced in 13.0.0**

---

If I type `f[x_Inte` and hit Tab to autocomplete, MMA correctly autocompletes this into `f[x_Integer`.

But if I type `f[ρ_Inte` and hit Tab, I get instead `f[Integer`, where `ρ_` has magically vanished.

Is my install faulty? Or is this a known bug? Is there any fix?

I am using `13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)`. Note that the behaviour is generic. You can replace `Integer` for any other predefined symbol, and `ρ` for any other variable other than pure letters (i.e., anything in brackets `[...]`), and the same issue happens.

Comment: You should know that x is the unknown :-)

Comment: I have the same behavior in version ```13.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)```

Comment: I reproduce the issue with version 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64. It is a bug, please report it to the support.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I just sent an email to `support@wolfram.com`. Will update if/when they reply.

Answer (score 1):

The bug has been confirmed by Wolfram support (2022-Jan-26):

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for taking the time to send your report.
>
> It does appear that the front-end's AutoComplete feature is not behaving properly with non-alphanumeric characters. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided, and added your contact information to the report so that you can be notified when it is resolved.
>
> We are always interested in improving Mathematica, and I want to thank you once again for bringing this issue to our attention. If you run into any other problems with any of our products or have any additional questions, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: Put `>` on the blank lines too